# Return array from a function using a pointer C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I am trying to understand pointers and functions, specifically how to use a pointer when returning an array from a function. I tried to write some code to see if I understand it but I clearly don't. Could you please look over and tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *elmntsum(int *a, int *b);

int main()
{
    int *z;
    int x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int y = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20} ;

    z = elmntsum(x, y);

    int t;

    for (t = 0 ; t < 10 ;t++){
        printf( "%d\n", z[t]);
    }
    return(0);
}

int *elmntsum(int *a, int *b){
    static int *c;
    int t;

    for (t = 0 ; t < 10 ;t++){
        c[t] = a[t] + b[t];
    }
    return(c);
}
```

Comment: This is invalid c `int x = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};` if it is compiling it should be rasing a warning. Also `return` is not a function don't use it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has many problems, the most important one is that you did not allocate space for `c`.

Don't use `static` if you don't really know why it is useful, it's certainly not useful in this situation.

The other important issue is the declaration of `x` and `y`, they should be declared as arrays, i.e.

```
int x[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
int y[10] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20} ;
```

You could do it like this

```
int *elmntsum(int *a, int *b, size_t count) {
    int *c;

    c = malloc(count * sizeof(*c));
    if (c == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for (size_t t = 0 ; t < count ;t++)
        c[t] = a[t] + b[t];
    return c;
}
```

And then your `main()` could look like this

```
int main()
{
    int *z;
    int x[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int y[10] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20} ;

    z = elmntsum(x, y, 10);
    if (z == NULL)
        return -1;
    for (size_t t = 0 ; t < 10 ;t++){
        printf("%d\n", z[t]);
    }
    free(z);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Thanks for the help. I was using Lynda and they gave an example which I was trying to copy as a template. Could you explain why not to use static? I was told it was there as the returned output was a local an not global variable.

Comment: Exactly because of that, because you will overwrite it every time you call `elmntsum()`, unless that's what you want and it could make sense in some context.